# Can't access service in controller

Tags: angularjs

So I'm trying to retrieve a token from the server but I'm encountering an error when trying to call a method in my service.

LoginController.js:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', [
            '$http', 'authService',
            LoginController
        ]);

    function LoginController(authService ) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.user = {};

        vm.login = function () {
            console.log("logging in");
            authService.getToken("admin", "admin")
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }, function (error) {
                    //TODO: error handling
                })
        };
    }
})();
```

authService.js:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('authService', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'REST_END_POINT',
            authService
        ]);

    function authService($http, $rootScope, REST_END_POINT){
        return {
            getToken: function(username, password) {
                var config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                };
                var data = {
                    username: login,
                    password: password
                };
                return $http.post(REST_END_POINT, +"/authenticate", data, config);
            }

        };
    }
})();
```

I keep getting this error :

TypeError: authService.getToken is not a function
    at LoginController.vm.login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add $http to your controller function.

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('LoginController', [
    '$http', 'authService',
     LoginController
  ]);

  function LoginController(_$http_needs_to_be_here, authService ) {
    ...
```

Comment: Seriously was that it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$http` from this line since you have it injected in your service already

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('LoginController', [
        'authService',
        LoginController
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong no of params in LoginController function. You have request angular to inject $http and authService. But you have  only one param in function. For more info pls read [Angular DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Re-write code:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', [
            '$http', 'authService',
            LoginController
        ]);

    function LoginController($http, authService ) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.user = {};

        vm.login = function () {
            console.log("logging in");
            authService.getToken("admin", "admin")
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }, function (error) {
                    //TODO: error handling
                })
        };
    }
})();
```